# CSS - Video does not fully fit its container

Tags: css, video

I use this simple code:

```
videocont {
    border: 2px solid red;
    flex: 1;
}
.videoconr video {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The video is displayed fine but although I set its `width` and `height` to `100%`, there is a little empty space at the top of the video:

[image]

Comment: Try to use margin property. You have link with more info https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_margin.asp

Answer (score 0):

Have you set a "height" property inside the video tag in html? If you remove it it will automize the height based on the width/height ratio of the video and the whitespace should be gone. (Source: just tried it in atom with another video that had width and height properties set)

Example: this gave me whitespace on top and below:

```
<video width="400px" height="400px" autoplay loop controls muted >
<source src="vid.mp4">

</video>
<style>
video {
    border: 2px solid red;
    flex: 1;
}
.video video {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

and this did not:

```
<video width="400px"  autoplay loop controls muted >
<source src="vid.mp4">

   </video>
  <style>
   video {
    border: 2px solid red;
    flex: 1;
     }
    .video video {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
```